# Create Mobile Site for a site you don't have access to

Tags: php, api, screen-scraping

I'd like to create a mobile site for a website where my highschool checks our grades. Effectively, I want to remotely login to the portal, and then go into the sub page where the students grades are and scrape them. This portal does not have an API that I'm aware of. I'm not really sure if this is possible with PHP/JS, and if it is, I'm not really sure how to start.

Anyone that has knowledge for this, can you point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Painful... you'd basically have to set up a full proxy. Grab a requested page, figure out which bits can be kept and which tossed, etc... As well as the privacy issues involved with your site requiring people to enter their user/pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no api, then you can only parse the raw html and try to get an re-design the information that way.

Comment: That's the idea, ive just never dealt with using a form and submitting it remotely, so that my code has access to the blocked html

Comment: You submit the form via a http-post. Then I think you will get returned some authentication cookie that you will have to send to server each time you request a protected page. It's not as hard to accomplish as it sounds ;). And get firebug for firefox, this will help you a lot. If you know how to use it, wireshark can also be a big help.

Comment: great. Do you know of any tutorials, examples, or documentation that can further show the steps

Comment: you could search for general information about the way web applicatiosn like one you want to "reimplement" are built.

Comment: or simply contact the admin ;)

Comment: I'm still not sure how I'm going to go about this. I'll leave it open for the day, and if no one responds, I'll mark your answer as correct

Comment: 1.: You post the filled in login-form to the server 2.: You extract the authentication cookie 3.: You request the blocked pages using this cookie  (All you have to do is to "simulate" the behaviour of a web browser, so analyse what your browser is doing and do the same)